# How to delay for few seconds in ajax/javascript/php before insertion

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<?php
    include_once("connect.php");
    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        $sno=$_POST['sno'];
        $start_date=$_POST['start_date'];
        $end_date=$_POST['end_date'];
        $amount=$_POST['amount'];
        $lease_id=$_POST['lease_id'];
        if($lease_id == 0){
            $lease_id=1;
        }
        $calendar_type=$_POST['calendar_type'];
        $rph=$_POST['start_date']." - ".$_POST['end_date'];
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_lease_details(lease_id,sno,start_date,end_date,amount,calendar_type,rph,stat) VALUES ('$lease_id','$sno','$start_date','$end_date','$amount','$calendar_type','$rph','not_paid')";

        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        if($result){

            echo "successfully inserted";
        }
    }
    mysql_close($rs);
    mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

I need to add a "loader" in order to make some delay before inserting into database. I tried my best but I couldn't, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You can use [sleep](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.sleep.php). The better question is why would you want to delay the insert? And stop using `mysql_*`, they're deprecated.

Comment: you can use javascript function. window.setTimeOut()

Comment: @Andrew where can i use sleep?, Im a beginner

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal how to include setTimeOut() inside that?

Comment: `<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>

       <script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
                
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
            }

           <?php
               echo "test();";
           ?>
       </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>`

Answer (score 3):

In php we can add dealy using sleep function. please check below code

```
     echo date('h:i:s') . "<br>";

    //sleep for 5 seconds
    sleep(5);

    //start again
    echo date('h:i:s');
```